# How to store application data locally so information can persist across application sessions

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of information stored in one large `List<T>` that acts like a tree, quite complex organizationally, but not too large. I need this information to persist across app closes and opens. Do I have to use SQL Server Compact Edition? Could I easily save it as an XML or JSON file? What is the easiest to use? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can easily store application data locally as XML or JSON; do so research and try it. If you run into trouble, post what you tried. I would not recommend SQL Server Compact.

Comment: The built in XML serializer is really easy to use. The Microsoft docs have some good examples.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I can suggest you to use SQL lite, and maybe instead of "tree" that you have in the List you can have that structure in the db or if you already have all that logic and wants to save as you mention like a json or xml you can do it.

Comment: It'll be great if all the people that score my answer as it is not useful, put their solutions, we can learn all.